# What are the white circles just before the runway holding point?

Tags: airport

What are the white circles before runway holding point? I tried looking on manual but couldn’t find anything

Comment: Can you include an illustration or photograph showing what you're referring to?

Comment: If you can add in the particular airport you've seen them at, someone might be able to find a photograph.

Answer (score 1):

These white circle were also marked with some range and bearing data. That means if your aircraft is in that circle, your vor and dme should read those marked values which in turn help the pilot to check serviceability/accuracy of vor dme. 
It’s manual version of test Vor to check accuracy of aircraft equipment.

Comment: Which white circles are "these white circles?"

Answer (score 1):

If they look like this one at KSJC
[image: VOR checkpoint at KSJC via google maps]
[https://www.google.com/maps/@37.356458,-121.9258751,158m/data=!3m1!1e3]

then it is a certified VOR receiver checkpoint.  These will be listed in the chart supplement (A/FD).

> San Jose (Norman Y. Mineta San Jose Intl) 114.1/SJC G 125 1.4 On runup
>   area Twy W and D.

The [*Standards for Airport Markings*](https://aeronav.faa.gov/Upload_313-d/supplements/CS_SW_20190425.pdf) should have information on all markings for US airports.  It has this information on the design and dimensions of VOR checkpoints.

[image]